# how implement a function to iterate over if its passed a Range

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I'm creating my own version of .each method in Ruby and I'm having trouble implementing it to work for the input of a Range (1..10).

```
module Enumerable
  # @return [Enumerable]
  def my_each
    return to_enum :my_each unless block_given?

    index = 0
    while index < size
      if is_a? Array
        yield self[index]
      elsif is_a? Hash
        yield keys[index], self[keys[index]]
      elsif is_a? Range
        yield self[index]
      end
      index += 1
    end
  end
end
```

I trying to get it to, if passed

```
r_list = (1..10)
r_list.my_each { |number| puts number }
```

The output would be

```
=> 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: There is a reason `each` is not in `Enumerable`: every enumerable object is supposed to provide their own `each`, which the methods in `Enumerable` can rely on to accurately provide iteration over the object's elements. That said... yielding `self.begin + index` should be okay.

Comment: Further to @Amadan's comment, consider `Enumerable#map`. There is also a method `Array#map` and of course `Array` includes `Enumerable`. We find that `[1].method(:map).owner #=> Array` and `[1].method(:map).super_method.owner #=> Enumerable`, so `arr.map { ... }` invokes `Array#map`. It's the same with every class `C` that includes `Enumerable`. `C` already has a method `C#each` so your `Enumerable#each` will not be used. The upshot is that it seems pointless to create an `Enumerable` method `each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique, that changes very little of this implementation, would be to convert your range to an array.

```
module Enumerable
  def my_each
    return to_enum :my_each unless block_given?

    index = 0
    while index < size
      if is_a? Array
        yield self[index]
      elsif is_a? Hash
        yield keys[index], self[keys[index]]
      elsif is_a? Range
        yield to_a[index]
      end
      index += 1
    end
  end
end

r_list = (1..10)
puts r_list.my_each { |number| puts number }
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```